What kinds of analysis can I do to improve my openings?
I am working in a project where I can analyze pgn games, so if I apply it to my own games, I would get a full map of the positions I have won as white/black and compare that directly with the positions I have lost (this includes transpositions, and not the order of the opening itself)
Now I know that there are positions in which I am consistently better, and there are other positions in which I am consistently worse. How should I proceed?
Should the study be guided so that I get better at my worse positions? Should I study those positions in which I have performed the best and try to guide my games in that direction? Should I try new openings to se how they fit my game?
Also, in terms of implementation, what would be an enhancement you could recommend so that my project can be more useful?
I attach the link to the project, please tell me what would you suggest in order to improve. Also, if you find the project useful, you can use it for your own games.
https://github.com/OscarFlores-IFi/targeted-strategic-chess-opening

I do not think this question is “opinion-based”. Chess is not just a matter of facts and citations, even though one moderator would like to pretend that it is. This was a decent question which took effort to put together and deserves better than the all too common drive-by closing that has happened here
